# Help to draw and hatch a parallelogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, tikz-shape, pattern

I have the following picture:

[image: trapezium]

I tried to draw it with tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm,usenames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}
\definecolor{antique}{rgb}{0.8, 0.58, 0.46}
\definecolor{pastelorange}{rgb}{1.0, 0.7, 0.28}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[trapezium, draw, very thin, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: mywork]

What I am not able to do:

- mirror the object
- fill it (hatch it) with colored stripes
- make the arrows (vectors)

Is it possible to do the same with 3D object (parallelepiped)?

Thanks all !

Comment: Please: one question per question! You have 4 here. 3 are arguably closely related enough to count as 1, but the 3D case should definitely be a different question. If you ask that one separately, please don't assume people know what a parallelepiped looks like. I have zero idea.

Comment: Note that hatching is different. Ti*k*Z calls it cross-hatching when two sets of lines are used, which cross each other e.g. northeast to southwest and southeast to northwest. I'm assuming you want just one set of lines since you specify 'stripes' and show that in your picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm,usenames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
% ateb https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700945/: addaswyd o gwestiwn JoudaBouda: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700934/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (p)[pattern={Lines[angle=120,line width=.1pt,distance=.5pt]}, pattern color=gray, trapezium, draw, very thin, trapezium right angle=120] at (0,0) {};
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=1pt]},ultra thin] (p.bottom left corner) ++(45:.5\pgflinewidth) coordinate (a) -- ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]p.bottom right corner);
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=1pt]},ultra thin] (a) -- ([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]p.top left corner);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: parallelogram with hatching and vectors]

Comment: The result makes my eyes go funny.

Comment: If you use `outer sep=0pt` for the node, you can just do `\path[very thin, every edge/.style=tips, -Stealth] (p.bottom left corner) edge (p.bottom right corner) edge (p.top left corner);`. (`very thin` is the same line width as for the node to scale the arrow tip appropriately w/o hard-coded numbers, `tips` only draws the tips but not the path unless `draw` is used. Of course, this is a very tiny trapezium (no text, no minimum sizes) so things might need adjustments.)

Answer (score 5):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
   
\begin{tkzelements}
   z.A         = point: new(0,0)
   z.B         = point: new(5,0)
   z.C         = point: new(1,4)
   T.ABC       = triangle: new (z.A,z.B,z.C)
   z.D = T.ABC : parallelogram ()
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzGetNodes
   \tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,D)
   \tkzFillPolygon[pattern={Lines[angle=60,distance=8pt]},
       pattern   color=black](A,...,D)
   \tkzDrawSegments[-stealth,line width=1pt](A,B A,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]